# Node js can't install canvas on windows

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm

I already tried installing it with the official Wiki documentation. No luck for me. I installed GTK and node-gyp too. I am not sure what's wrong.

Here is my error message.

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\is vertical>npm i canvas

> canvas@1.6.10 install C:\Users\User\node_modules\canvas
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\User\node_modules\canvas>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build t
ools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, please install v120 bui
ld tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-cli
ck the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\User\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v9.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\package.json'
npm WARN User No description
npm WARN User No repository field.
npm WARN User No README data
npm WARN User No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! canvas@1.6.10 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.6.10 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-08T22_35_58_874Z-debug.log
```